# Repeat multiple charts on each page of subreport

Tags: reporting-services, charts, repeat, subreport

I've a SSRS page which has header, two charts with different datasets and a subreport below charts.

When I run the page and drill down (I click on one of the bars of chart, it calls itself) and data populates in subreport which spans multiple pages.

My problem is I want to repeat those charts on each page. I've searched and tried a lot However nothing worked forme.

How can I repeat charts in multiple pages of subreport? Please note that I've got charts with different data sets and that subreport is used at multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply mike.
I believe it can not be achieved using subreports. hence, i embedded that subreport tablix into report and did as suggested by mike(charts went into header row).

Since tablix accepts only single dataset, i created a big dataset that has all the fields for two charts and data and applied required settings to get the job done.

It worked for me(at least to get the job done.).

Answer (score 1):

I had a report that after each record (customer), I put a page break so that each record got its own numbers in one page. I also wanted to add a graph specific to only that customer. So i added the graphs into a table. In the table where my graphs were place, I added a parent group group - the same group as my data and I checked that the table also had the page break on the same group. This separated each record into a page each and also added the graphs to its corresponding record.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to wrap the two charts and subreport inside a tablix.  The dataset for the tablix would be one that returns a single row.

The two charts would go into the header row(s). The subreport would go in the Detail row.

Row and Column sizes need to be expanded to fit the chart and subreport sizes. There may be only one or two Columns depending on your layout.

Then I would use the dreaded "Advanced Mode" technique to get the header row(s) to repeat on each page, e.g.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "returns a single row"?

Comment: Eg SELECT 1 AS Any_Value. A Table in SSRS must refer to a Dataset, but in this scenario you don't want the layout to repeat.